# Rails Geocoder near method limiting results to 100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, rails-geocoder

I'm working with Rails, Mongoid, and Geocoder. My issue is `Location.near` is limiting results returned to 100, even for results that should yield over 100. I need a way to return all the results for any location.

```
Location.near([28.4989, -87.7271], 1).count
=> 100
```

I tried several methods and it looks like I should be doing something similar to the following, which still returns 100.

```
Location.near([28.4989, -87.7271]).limit(200).count
=> 100
```

---

**Edit:**
It appears that this is a known issue with the `near` method and its default limit of 100. I was able to find a Mongoid query that returns all results.

```
Location.where(:coordinates.within => { "$center" => [ [-87.7271, 28.4989], 0.01] }).count
=> 186
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue with the `near` method and its default limit of 100. I was able to find a Mongoid query that returns all results.

```
Location.where(:coordinates.within => { "$center" => [ [-87.7271, 28.4989], 0.01] }).count
=> 186
```

Comment: Hmm... I get an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `within' for :coordinates:Symbol) -- is there something I missed. I'm very interested in how you got this working being new to Mongo/Mongoid/Geocoder

Comment: Same issue as Tim. Wonder if there has been a change in the API. Will post back if I find an answer.

Comment: This is what works for me: `Location.where(:coordinates => { "$within" => { "$center" => [[-87.7271, 28.4989], 1 ]}})`